# How can I tell whether ReactJS is in development mode from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a [Mixin](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins) for ReactJS. I'd like it to do some validation, but only when ReactJS is being used in [development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118915/how-to-turn-on-off-reactjs-development-mode).

How can I determine from JavaScript whether ReactJS is in development or production mode?

Comment: You can set `__DEV__` variable with webpack..

Comment: If you're writing a Mixin, you probably don't want to force users to rebuild ReactJS themselves.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ReactJS source uses a variable called [`__DEV__`](https://github.com/facebook/react/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=__DEV__&type=Code) to track this, but it's not exported, so it's unavailable to your Mixin.

Its consequences are, however. When you break an invariant, for example, dev mode ReactJS will give you a nice description of what went wrong. In production mode, it will give a generic error telling you to use the dev version.

We can use this to build a function which determines if React is in dev mode:

```js
function isDevReact() {
  try {
    React.createClass({});
  } catch(e) {
    if (e.message.indexOf('render') >= 0) {
      return true;  // A nice, specific error message
    } else {
      return false;  // A generic error message
    }
  }
  return false;  // should never happen, but play it safe.
};
```

This works because the exception for not implementing a `render` method is different in the two modes:

```
Development: "Invariant Violation: createClass(...): Class specification must implement a `render` method. Inline JSX script:16"
Production:  "Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings. Inline JSX script:16"
```

The word "render" is specific to the invariant we violated, so it only shows up in the dev version's exception.

Comment: I can see "React.createClass is deprecated since React 15.5.0" in the console, but the message is "__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createClass is not a function" (I'm using start-react-app). I'm searching for "react___default.a.createClass" and it works, but feels pretty fragile.