# React - Minified exception occurred

Tags: npm, reactjs, browserify

I have React js installed via NPM and using browserify to manage components in react. When an exception occurs in React, the console shows as

> "Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev
>   environment for the full error message and additional helpful
>   warnings."

How do I enable full error messages ?

Comment: Well, it's telling you, "use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings."

Comment: I'm not referencing the React Js file directly in my source. I'm requiring react through browserify like var React = require('react');

How do I configure browserify to use the non-minified version ?

Comment: This is literally in the first page of the documentation about using react with browserify - is your `NODE_ENV` set to `production`?

Comment: Setting the environment variable to 'development' resolved the issue. Thanks a lot Benjamin Gruenbaum for the quick response :)

Comment: You're very welcome, now I _could_ write an answer but I think there would be better value in you writing the answer ala Q&A style.

Comment: Better question: why can't the minified exception have a stack trace?  It's a pretty big problem when no exception is occuring in dev mode...

Comment: @Andy: I thought that building the stacktrace is a pretty expensive operation so it's simply skipped for production. But yeah, I've got the same problem here... The bug does not occur in the dev version ;)

Comment: @Laoujin interesting point!  Looks like a lot of people want a separate option to turn production error messages on/off: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2686

Comment: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/748969886433546240

Comment: I execute set NODE_ENV=development&& node app.js from my package.json and still only get minified errors :(

Comment: i have a question, i am not using React at all and i am still getting this error. I dont even have npm installed on my server. why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Setting NODE_ENV to development as Benjamin Gruenbaum pointed out in the comment resolved the issues.

```
set NODE_ENV=development
```

Comment: In gulpfile I do `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'` but still get generic message??

Comment: Could you try executing `set NODE_ENV=development` in the command prompt and see ?

Comment: I wrote this on the command prompt in the project's base directory. However, it seems to have no effect.(I am using Windows 7)

Comment: [Other ways to switch React to dev mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118915/how-to-turn-on-off-reactjs-development-mode) in case this one doesn't work for you.

Comment: "WTF why am I getting this error?" let me take a quick look at StackOverflow - oh snap - I answered it in the comments. Story of my life -_-

Comment: Also if you've packaged with webpack/browserify in production mode changing this later won't help you out; you'll need to recompile in development mode.

Answer (score 16):

If you are encountering this issue with Karma + Webpack, the following Webpack configuration fixed the issue for me when running tests:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
        }
    })
]
```

Answer (score 14):

I FINALLY SOLVED THIS.

If you're like me and ran that command to set NODE_ENV and it's literally never worked, check if you're linking to react.min.js instead of the full versions of the files.

Link to the full versions and it should work like a charm. :D

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you did to link to the full version?  Did you `require('./node_modules/react/dist/react.js')`?

Comment: in your html using the script tag src attribute, I wasn't linking to the full version, I was using the production version. This was before I understood how to use bower so I wasn't understanding the difference.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using jspm to bundle your code, note that version 0.16.24 imports the minified "production" version of React, which throws this error. My temporary solution was to downgrade jspm to 0.16.23.

*edit* Future versions of jspm will allow you to declare production vs. development versions (see [jspm beta documentation](http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/))

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue, and for me I didn't need to disable minification or use react source.  My script was just loading before the root element.  So I just moved the script out of the head and below the div in the index file source code and that fixed it.

Changed my index.jade from this:

```
html
 head
   title Super coo site
   script(src="bundle.js")
 body
   div#root
```

To this:

```
html
 head
   title Super coo site
 body
   div#root
   script(src="bundle.js")
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when my render method returned `undefined` eg

```
render() {
    let view;
    // Not paying attention and slip a case where view won't get assigned a value
    if(this.props.foo == 'hello') {
        view = <HelloView />
    }
    else if(this.props.foo == 'bye') {
        view = <ByeView />
    }
    return view;
}
```

This will trigger the error when this.props.foo is 'hi'

Comment: This is true, check if you use some variable in the render function that isn't created yet or undefined, it's really misleading error message but this works for me

Answer (score 2):

Have you check the DOM element that you are trying render ? I had this error before due to a silly mistake. The worst part is bundle was minified. The element **id** is not same

**Index.html**

```
<div id="ds-app"></div>
```

**app.jsx**

```
React.DOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [version 15.2](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1520-july-1-2016), production React error messages (`NODE_ENV=production`) now include a URL that you can visit where you can see the original, unobfuscated error.

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/748969886433546240

You should consider upgrading to React 15.2 in order to get access to these error messages. Additionally, some production crash reporting tools [automatically unminify these errors](https://blog.getsentry.com/2016/08/10/react-minified-errors.html) for you.

Comment: It's important to point out, for this answer, that he's speaking specifically about error messages _in production mode_, for which this point is indeed relevant.

Answer (score 0):

use the min.js files in production or bundle your application code with `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

If your package.json scripts has `dll`， try exec `npm run dll` or `yarn run dll`.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing my first Shopify app and using heroku to host it. Nothing worked for me until I discovered this topic and one other. Here is my vite.config.js:

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import "dotenv/config";

/**
 * @type {import('vite').UserConfig}
 */
export default {
    define: {
        "process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY": JSON.stringify(process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY),
        "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    },
    //plugins: [react()],
    plugins: [
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== `production` ? react({
            jsxRuntime: `classic`,
        }) : react(),
    ],
};
```

NODE_ENV=development

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of package-lock.json. Delete and redeploy