# No JavaScript is running in heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am building an application in rails. All of my javscript code is working on my local machine. However, after I deployed to heroku I noticed none of my custom javascript code in my assets/javascripts is running in heroku. I do have bootstrap and bootstrap seems to be working fine (including all of the built in javascript).

I am getting this error in the browsers console: `Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.`

My application.js folder looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require d3
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require bootstrap
//= require react_bootstrap
//= require react_bootstrap_style
//= require jquery-readyselector
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I just tried heroku run rake assets:precompile and it didn't work.

Comment: just tried that. It still didn't work

Comment: Try googling that error message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586928/react-minified-exception-occurred

Comment: how is your `production.rb` layed out