# How to set React to production mode when using Gulp

Tags: javascript, python, flask, reactjs, tornado

I need to run React in production mode, which presumably entails defining the following somewhere in the enviornment:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```

The issue is that I'm running this behind Tornado (a python web-server), not Node.js. I also use Supervisord to manage the tornado instances, so it's not abundantly clear how to set this in the running environment.

I do however use Gulp to build my jsx files to javascript.

Is it possible to somehow set this inside Gulp? And if so, how do I check that React is running in production mode?

Here is my Gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
        babelify = require('babelify'),
        browserify = require('browserify'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
        source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
        uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
        buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

var vendors = [
    'react',
    'react-bootstrap',
    'jquery',
];

gulp.task('vendors', function () {
        var stream = browserify({
                        debug: false,
                        require: vendors
                });

        stream.bundle()
                    .pipe(source('vendors.min.js'))
                    .pipe(buffer())
                    .pipe(uglify())
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));

        return stream;
});

gulp.task('app', function () {
        var stream = browserify({
                        entries: ['./app/app.jsx'],
                        transform: [babelify],
                        debug: false,
                        extensions: ['.jsx'],
                        fullPaths: false
                });

        vendors.forEach(function(vendor) {
                stream.external(vendor);
        });

        return stream.bundle()
                                 .pipe(source('build.min.js'))
                                 .pipe(buffer())
                                 .pipe(uglify())
                                 .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));

});

gulp.task('watch', [], function () {
    // gulp.watch(['./app/**/*.jsx'], ['app', browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch(['./app/**/*.jsx'], ['app']);
});

gulp.task('browsersync',['vendors','app'], function () {
        browserSync({
            server: {
                baseDir: './',
            },
            notify: false,
            browser: ["google chrome"]
    });
});

gulp.task('default',['browsersync','watch'], function() {});
```

Comment: From what I can gather from the react documentation on production vs developments means using a different artifact. See the download page: http://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html

Comment: React is installed via npm, i.e. "npm install react". There is a seamless way of switching between dev and production, that's what I'm asking for in the question

Comment: You can set the environment variable before running gulp in production : NODE_ENV='production' gulp. The react library will read from this to remove logging messages and alerts and uglifyJS will take care of the rest [http://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html](http://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## 2017 - Edit: anyone trying to set up React in Gulp for a new project: Just use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

---

***Step I:*** Add the following to your gulpfile.js somewhere

```
gulp.task('apply-prod-environment', function() {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});
```

***Step II:*** Add it to your default task (or whichever task you use to serve/build your app)

```
// before: 
// gulp.task('default',['browsersync','watch'], function() {});
// after:
   gulp.task('default',['apply-prod-environment', 'browsersync','watch'], function() {});
```

---

***OPTIONAL:*** If you want to be ABSOLUTELY CERTAIN that you are in prod mode, you can create the following slightly enhanced task instead of the one in Step I:

```
gulp.task('apply-prod-environment', function() {
    process.stdout.write("Setting NODE_ENV to 'production'" + "\n");
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
        throw new Error("Failed to set NODE_ENV to production!!!!");
    } else {
        process.stdout.write("Successfully set NODE_ENV to production" + "\n");
    }
});
```

Which will throw the following error if NODE_ENV is ever not set to 'production'

```
[13:55:24] Starting 'apply-prod-environment'...
[13:55:24] 'apply-prod-environment' errored after 77 μs
[13:55:24] Error: Failed to set NODE_ENV to production!!!!
```

Comment: In what case would the error be thrown? Is there a situation where you can't write to your personal environment variables?

Comment: no such case to my knowledge. optional step is probably unnecessary actually.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the order of tasks in gulp isn't technically guaranteed.  So could watch and browsersync not happen before applying the prod environment?

Comment: I was expecting a sensible change in size, but it seems that the difference is about 2ko difference (not compressed), could someone confirm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881633/how-to-fix-redux-node-env-errors-with-gulp-browserify @monarch

Answer (score 8):

Similar to the other answers, but hopefully gives someone a starting point:

```
var vendorList = ['react', 'react-dom'];

gulp.task('vendor-dev', function() {
    browserify()
        .require(vendorList)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/dev/js'));
});

gulp.task('vendor-production', function() {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
    browserify()
        .require(vendorList)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/production/js'));
});
```

The main difference is I am explicitly setting the NODE_ENV prior to bundling the vendor libraries. Gulp tasks aren't guaranteed to run in order.

**Am I running in production mode?**

If you remove the uglify line (and prior buffer) you will notice that both the dev and production builds are near identical in size - and match in line count.

The difference is the production version will be littered with:

```
"production" !== "production" ? [show dev error] : [no nothing]
```

Most reputable minify'ers (I believe) will strip out deadend code, such as the above, which will always result in false.

**But really how do I tell?**

Easiest method to be sure, would be goto the console of your running application and type:

```
React.createClass.toString();
```

The output should be:

```
"function (e){var t=function(e,t,n){this.__reactAutoBindMap&&c(this),"[....and more and more]
```

If you find the createClass in the react source, you will see:

```
createClass: function (spec) {
    var Constructor = function (props, context, updater) {
      // This constructor is overridden by mocks. The argument is used
      // by mocks to assert on what gets mounted.

      if ("production" !== 'production') {
        "production" !== 'production' ? warning(this instanceof Constructor, 'Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or ' + 'JSX instead. See: react-legacyfactory') : undefined;
      }

      // Wire up auto-binding
      if (this.__reactAutoBindMap) {
        bindAutoBindMethods(this);
      }
```

Notice how the console output skips straight through to `this.__reactAutobind`, because you are running in production mode, and using an minify'er, all the !== 'production' warngins and checks have been skipped over.

Comment: Great. Explicitly setting the NODE_ENV in the task itself was the only way it worked for me.

Comment: No worries. Yep, it was the same for me

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately none of the above answers work, because setting `process.env.NODE_ENV` has no effect in Browserify. The resulting bundle still has `process.env.NODE_ENV` references in it and hence

- Browserify will not `require()` the React production version modules,
- the minifier will not be able to remove dead code, and
- the application will still be running in debug mode.

This is unfortunately not the only place where this approach is offered as the correct answer :-(

---

The correct approach can be found in e.g.

- https://github.com/hughsk/envify/issues/15#issuecomment-62229101
- https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#browserify

You need to switch the envify transform to be a global one, e.g.

```
# note the "-g" instead of the usual "-t"
$ browserify ... -g [ envify --NODE_ENV production ] ....
```

or in `gulpfile.js`

```
browserify(...)
    ...
    .transform('envify', {
        global:   true, // also apply to node_modules
        NODE_ENV: debug ? 'development' : 'production',
    })
    ...
    .bundle()
    ...
    .pipe(gulpif(!debug, babelMinify())) // my example uses gulp-babel-minify
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To set React in production mode you need to set your NODE_ENV variable to production and uglify your JS as an extra step.

You're already taking care of the uglification, for setting your NODE_ENV variable :

- Set the variable while running the gulp task :

`NODE_ENV='production' gulp`

- OR set it from inside your gulpfile by doing something like this :

`gulp.task('set-production-env', function() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});`

Comment: how do I check that React is working in production mode? Is there a way to check the mode in the dev console?

Comment: One way would be to trigger something that would cause a warning and check that no warning logs are present in the console. 
For example, map an array to a bunch of components and don't give them a key. If nothing is written to the console, then you're in production mode. 
Also, make sure the react lib is properly minified, uglified and gzipped for filesize.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: another way is to check the size of your final, minified app/browserify bundle. i just saw my bundle size drop by about 100kB with production set.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use handy way with `gulp-environments`:

```
var environments = require('gulp-environments');

var production = environments.production;

gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    // only minify the compiled JS in production mode
    .pipe(production(uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/app/js/"));
```

To run gulp in production mode:

```
gulp build --env=production
```