# Redux NODE_ENV errors with Gulp/Browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, redux, browserify

I'm getting this error message on a React/Redux app that is minified and packaged with Browserify and Gulp and deployed to Heroku.

`bundle.js:39 You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux.`

But it seems the build step is being done in `NODE_ENV = 'production'`.

I've a task that set the env variables like so

```
gulp.task('apply-prod-environment', function() {
  return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});
```

And the logs on Heroku show the ENV is production:

[image]

To guarantee the `apply-prod-environment`  runs before the other tasks, I'm using `RunSequence` Gulp plugin.

```
gulp.task('buildProd', cb => {
  runSequence(
    'apply-prod-environment',
    'task-1',
    'task-2',
    'etc',
    cb
  );
});
```

---

**EDIT**
**Second Try..**

```
import envify from 'envify/custom';

function buildJS(sourceFile, {setEnv}) {
  return browserify(sourceFile)
    .transform(babelify, {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
    })
    .transform(envify({
      NODE_ENV: setEnv
    }))
    .bundle()
    .on('error', (e) =>  {
      gutil.log(e);
    });
}
```

**Still Getting same Error**

**Third Try..**

```
function buildJS(sourceFile, {setEnv}) {
  return browserify(sourceFile)
    .transform(babelify, {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
    })
    .transform(
      {global: true},
      envify({
        NODE_ENV: setEnv
      })
    )
    .bundle()
    .on('error', (e) =>  {
      gutil.log(e);
    });
}
```

**Still Getting same Error**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479372/use-node-env-in-source-code-to-control-build-process-with-webpack

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this same problem and I ended up using [loose-envify](https://github.com/zertosh/loose-envify) to mock the environment variables that I wanted to override.

Then, my gulp task looked like this:

```
gulp.task('javascript:prod', function() {
return browserify("app/main.js", { debug: !IS_PROD })
    .transform("babelify", { presets: [ "es2015", "react" ], plugins: [ "transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-function-bind", "transform-object-assign" ] })
    .transform('loose-envify', { NODE_ENV: 'production' })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/javascripts/"))
    .pipe(rev.manifest({merge:true, base: 'build/assets'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets'));
});
```

Comment: Hmm. this is still not working. Is there anything else that needs to be set to fix?

Comment: I can't remember what I did because it was several months ago. Do you know if Heroku is running your 'buildProd' task as part of the build pack? Or are you running it locally and then pushing the pre-built files?

Comment: buildProd task is running on Heroku. Build log says it's running in 'production'.

Comment: A couple of questions... 1) Do you know which build pack you're using on Heroku? 2) Do you have Webpack, Babel and loaders listed in package.json under dependencies or devDependencies?  I assume they're under dependencies since ReactJS is actually being compiled. My guess is that you either have something incorrect in your gulp file or the Heroku build pack is running the gulp task using a different ENV that not production.

Comment: Using Node buildpack. Using Gulp / Browserify not Webpack. Most dependencies are in dependencies not devDependencies so that we can run the build on Heroku (among other things like CI).