# Import only specific components in react

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, react-chartjs

I'm working on a web project with react.
How can I import only 3 Components from a library.
I have used:

```
import Line, Bar, Doughnut from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

gives an error.

```
import Line from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Bar from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Doughnut from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

makes all Line, Bar and Doughnut elements act as Doughnut elements.

Using

```
import {Line, Bar, Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

loads the whole library, which is something I don't want.

NOTE: I use that import in multiple files.

Comment: `import { Doughnut, Line, Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'` try this one

Comment: `import Line from 'react-chartjs-2/Line';
import Bar from 'react-chartjs-2/Bar';
import Doughnut from 'react-chartjs-2/Doughnut';`
Could it work? (I didn't test it, just want to give it a try.)

Comment: What do you mean whole lib? take a look at [git repo](https://github.com/gor181/react-chartjs-2). It should work as you want

Comment: @TheReason [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34241128/3327294)

Comment: @AndreLee sadly that doesn't work, neither does `import Line from 'react-chartjs-2/components/line';`

Comment: @AndreLee No that doesn't work either, also replacing the '/' with '.' doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about how the author building, packaging, exporting the components/modules/classes.

Take a look at the [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/gor181/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/src/gulpfile.js) and [/lib](https://github.com/gor181/react-chartjs-2/tree/master/lib) of react-chartjs-2, you will see each class wasn't exported as a module ([CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules)), so you only can import the class **Doughnut** (or other classes) like this:

`import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2'`

unless you separate the code and rebuild them yourself.

If you are interested in why react-bootstrap can do that, check its [webpack config](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/webpack/base.config.js), [build tools](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/tree/master/tools), and [code structure](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/tree/master/src). And more we can get from:

- file structure of **react-chartjs-2**'s distribution

  [image: file structure of react-chartjs-2's distribution]
- file structure of **react-bootstrap**'s distribution

  [image: file structure of react-bootstrap's distribution]