# Very heavy bundle size of react development website

Tags: performance, reactjs, webpack, source-maps

I am creating a react website. Its almost ready but when I am debugging it, its load time is **1.2 Minutes** and bundle size is **28 MB**.

I have tried following solutions without success so far:

1. https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/two-quick-ways-to-reduce-react-apps-size-in-production-82226605771a#.qfpspcha4
2. https://hackernoon.com/optimising-your-application-bundle-size-with-webpack-e85b00bab579#.t3vabgy27
3. [How to minimize the size of webpack's bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239731/how-to-minimize-the-size-of-webpacks-bundle)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing your devtool setting? I believe inline-source-map is the reason for the large file size. More info on the different devtool settings [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/). For production I personally use `devtool:'cheap-module-source-map'` and have great success with it. I hope this help some, webpack can sure be frustrating at times.

Also to have a lighter dev build I would suggest to use `devtool:'eval'`, It's probably the most efficient as far as development goes.

Comment: When using `devtool:'eval'`, nothing happening.