# Tree shaking create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, rollupjs, react-scripts

I created my React app with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and now use TypeScript with [create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript).

Everything works ok, but the problem is - especially because I use the good but heavy [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) - the size of the built bundle is quite big - almost reaching 1MB.

How can I use tree shaking tools (like in Webpack 2 or [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup)?
I don't want to `eject` already so seems like I don't really have access to the Webpack configuration.

I wish it was possible to tree shake a minified code :)

Thanks!

Comment: relevant github issue https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2748

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If your project was built with create-react-app, the latest version has the fix, just update react-scripts to version 2.0.4 or higher.

`npm install react-scripts@latest --save`

This new version has excellent tree shaking thanks to the updated dependencies. I've tested with both material-ui and mdi-material-ui.

Answer (score 7):

We rewrote our imports for `material-ui` in our [create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) project by changing them from this style:

```js
import {FloatingActionButton} from "material-ui";
```

to this:

```js
import FloatingActionButton from "material-ui/FloatingActionButton";
```

**Edit:**
This gives a little more context: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11916#issuecomment-401214838

Comment: Mike, have you found a better way to do this?

Comment: No, but we also haven't upgraded to the latest version yet.  We are quite behind.

Comment: Mike, the latest create-react-app was released a few hours ago and has the fix we need. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use typscript, my fix was to change `"module": "commonjs",` to `"module": "ESNext",` in all `tsconfig.json` files.