# How to import a single function in create-react-app? (tree shaking is not working)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, webpack, create-react-app, ionic-react

I'm using create-react-app (`react-scripts` 4.0.3)/Ionic React to build a mobile app.

I'm having trouble with tree shaking, which [according to this answer has been supported since v2.x of create-react-app.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52638942/1209486)

I'm using [Webpack Bundle Analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to analyzer my bundle size.  I'm splitting up the bundle with `React.lazy()` and `Suspense`.

However, I noticed an issue in which a whole file is being imported instead of just a function.

I'm using [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) and I have a list of functions, **queries.tsx**:

```
import { addDataReferences } from '../utils/dataRefs';

export function useLoginStatusCookie(): UseQueryResult<boolean, Error> {
  const t0 = performance.now();
  return useQuery<boolean, Error>(
    queryKeyCookieLoginStatus,
    async () => doWeHaveLoginToken()
  );
}

export function useSomeData(
  queryKey: string,
  query: string,
): UseQueryResult<MyDataReferences[], Error> {
  return useQuery<MyDataReferences[], Error>(
    queryKey,
    async () => fetchGetWithUserAuth(query),
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        if (data?.[0]) {
          data.map(addDataReferences);
        }
      },
    },
  );
}
```

Now, in my React component, I import `useLoginStatusCookie()` like this:

```
import { useLoginStatusCookie } from '../../queries';
```

What I expected this to do was to simply import the `useLoginStatusCookie` function and not the `useSomeData` function, and definitely not the `dataRefs.tsx` file imported by the `useSomeData` function.

The bundles are split so that `useLoginStatusCookie` is in my main bundle (the first bundle to load), and the `useSomeData` function isn't called until a subsequent bundle.

However, when I inspect the bundle content with Webpack Bundle Analyzer, I see that the entire content of `queries.tsx` and `dataRefs.tsx` is loaded in the initial bundle.

How do I import only a single exported function in create-react-app so that the entire file isn't pulled in to my bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by putting each function in a separate file.