# Does removing unused imports have an impact on bundle size and build time in Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I have a Reactjs application created using Create React app which while starting and building gives a lot of warnings which states that I have unused vars or imports in my Components.

```
./src/components/home/Header.js
    Line 10:   'Switch' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
    Line 10:   'Route' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
```

Does having `no-unused-vars` have a considerable impact on final bundle size and build time of the application. Can I reduce build time and bundle size by removing all these warnings?

Comment: Yes, removing these will reduce size but not much. You need to do uglify, if you really want to reduce size.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ShubhamBatra. I think Create React app comes with uglify out of box. I was looking for ways to optimize build size and time.

Comment: Yes, uglify is out of box but it reduce my app size from 11.1 mb to 1.89 mb. you should see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239731/how-to-minimize-the-size-of-webpacks-bundle/34241128#34241128

Answer (score 6):

Checkout this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer. And run

```
source-map-explorer bundle.js
```

It will give you detailed screenshot of your bundle file like which package is taking too much file size and all. Change the way you are importing packages mentioned in [How to minimize the size of webpack's bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239731/how-to-minimize-the-size-of-webpacks-bundle/34241128#34241128) and also if some particular package is causing a size issue then switch to alternative packages.