# How can I speed up a React render() method that generates a huge DOM?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

## The `HtmlTable` component

Imagine a simple `HtmlTable` React component. It renders data based on a 2-dimensional array passed to it via `data` prop, and it can also limit the number of columns and rows via `rowCount` and `colCount` props. Also, we need the component to handle huge arrays of data (tens of thousands of rows) without pagination.

```
class HtmlTable extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var {rowCount, colCount, data} = this.props;
        var rows = this.limitData(data, rowCount);

        return <table>
            <tbody>{rows.map((row, i) => {
                var cols = this.limitData(row, colCount);
                return <tr key={i}>{cols.map((cell, i) => {
                    return <td key={i}>{cell}</td>
                })}</tr>
            })}</tbody>
        </table>
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    limitData(data, limit) {
        return limit ? data.slice(0, limit) : data;
    }
}
```

## The `rowHeights` props

Now we want to let the user change the row heights and do it dynamically. We add a `rowHeights` prop, which is a map of row indices to row heights:

```
{
    1: 100,
    4: 10,
    21: 312
}
```

We change our `render` method to add a `style` prop to `<tr>` if there's a height specified for its index (and we also use `shallowCompare` for `shouldComponentUpdate`):

```
    render() {
        var {rowCount, colCount, data, rowHeights} = this.props;
        var rows = this.limitData(data, rowCount);

        return <table>
            <tbody>{rows.map((row, i) => {
                var cols = this.limitData(row, colCount);
                var style = rowHeights[i] ? {height: rowHeights[i] + 'px'} : void 0;
                return <tr style={style} key={i}>{cols.map((cell, i) => {
                    return <td key={i}>{cell}</td>
                })}</tr>
            })}</tbody>
        </table>
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
    }
```

So, if a user passes a `rowHeights` prop with the value `{1: 10}`, we need to update only one row -- the second one.

## The performance problem

However, in order to do the diff, React would have to rerun the whole render method and recreate tens of thousands of `<tr>`s. This is extremely slow for large datasets.

I thought about using `shouldComponentUpdate`, but it wouldn't have helped -- the bottleneck happened before we even tried to update `<tr>`s. The bottleneck happens during recreation of the whole table in order to do the diff.

Another thing I thought about was caching the `render` result, and then `splice`ing changed rows, but it seems to defeat the purpose of using React at all.

Is there a way to not rerun a "large" `render` function, if I know that only a tiny part of it would change?

**Edit:** Apparently, caching is the way to go... For example, here's [a discussion of a similar problem in React's Github.](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1654) And React Virtualized seems to be using [a cell cache](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Grid/Grid.js#L234) (though I might be missing something).

**Edit2:** Not really. Storing and reusing the "markup" of the component is still slow. Most of it comes from reconciling the DOM, which is something I should've expected. Well, now I'm totally lost. This is what I did to prepare the "markup":

```
    componentWillMount() {
        var {rowCount, colCount, data, rowHeights={}} = this.props;
        var rows = this.limitData(data, rowCount);
        this.content = <table>
            <tbody>{rows.map((row, i) => {
                var cols = this.limitData(row, colCount);
                var style = rowHeights[i] ? {height: rowHeights[i] + 'px'} : void 0;
                return <tr style={style} key={i}>{cols.map((cell, i) => {
                    return <td key={i}>{cell}</td>
                })}</tr>
            })}</tbody>
        </table>
    }

    render() {
        return this.content
    }
```

Comment: Let's say the specs don't allow for pagination. (Edited that in).

Comment: I'd go and make a `TableRowComponent`. Then you should be able to just rerender that row. There's no way around the DOM having to do a reflow but it would at least speed up incremental renders. It won't do anything for the initial render though. Pagination would be needed for that I think.

Comment: Still, we'd have thousands of `<TableRowComponent>`s to **create** (not render) during `render` function on each props update. Or am I wrong to think that?

Comment: That's where you use `shouldComponentUpdate` so each row can see if it needs to render. I'm not 100% sure it would work but I think it would help. I could be wrong so I'm commenting not answering :)

Comment: The problem is not in updating rows, it's in generating rows in `render` in order to do the diff. The `<HtmlTable>`'s `render` function is slow even if nothing happens on update, because it has to recreate those thousands of virtual `<tr>` elements.

Comment: it took 500ms to 1s to render 10k items in chrome with react for me. how slow is your slow mean?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use something like this? https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/ It lazily renders rows.

Comment: I think what @sbichenko is saying is to have a component for each row. In each of those, use `shouldComponentUpdate`, if the style for that row hasn't changed, return `false`. Therefore an update of `{1: 10}` would only run `render()` for that one row.

Comment: Do you really need to render the whole table to the DOM? You could only render the items that fit on screen (and few above/below the visible area), then update the contents in response to scroll events.

Comment: I'm not familiar with reactJs but I hada a similar problem once. My performance problem wasn't creating ~50000 grid nodes, but inserting them continously in the DOM which triggers a browser-based rerender of the page. Temporarely removing my gridview control from DOM during loading and sorting reduced this issues. I'm not sure but I think elements with 'display: none' are also not rendered onChange. Maybe you want to give it a try and set your tables style to display: none during render.

Comment: Well, I know that this is not a solution, but dont forget to build react for production as this generally speeds up performance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118915/how-to-turn-on-off-reactjs-development-mode

Comment: All the solutions provided are bad, use a functional component since you've no lifecycle methods needed, just `const htmlTable = props => <table>...`

Comment: @caub How does that solve the underlying problem?

Comment: converting the row map() to a for loop should actually speed it up quite a bit.

Answer (score 23):

For this particular case I would recommend [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) or [fixed-data-table](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/) as mentioned by others. Both components will limit DOM interaction, by lazy loading data, i.e. only render the portion of the table that is visible.

Speaking more generally, the [MobX documentation](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/) has an [excellent page on react performance](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/react-performance.html). Please check it out. Here are the bullet points.

#### 1. Use many small components

> [mobx-react](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#faq)'s `@observer` components will track all values they use and re-render if any of them changes. So the smaller your components are, the smaller the change they have to re-render; it means that more parts of your user interface have the possibility to render independently of each other.
>
> `observer` allows components to render independently from their parent

#### 2. Render lists in dedicated components

> This is especially true when rendering big collections. React is notoriously bad at rendering large collections as the reconciler has to evaluate the components produced by a collection on each collection change. It is therefore recommended to have components that just map over a collection and render it, and render nothing else:

#### 3. Don't use array indexes as keys

> Don't use array indexes or any value that might change in the future as key. Generate id's for your objects if needed. See also this [blog](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

#### 4. Dereference values lately

> When using [mobx-react](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react) it is recommended to dereference values as late as possible. This is because MobX will re-render components that dereference observable values automatically. If this happens deeper in your component tree, less components have to re-render.

#### 5. Bind functions early

> This tip applies to React in general and libraries using PureRenderMixin especially, try to avoid creating new closures in render methods.

Example (*untested*)

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { observable } from 'mobx';


const HtmlTable = observer(({
  data,
}) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <TBody rows={data} />
    </table>
  );
}

const TBody = observer(({
  rows,
}) => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {rows.map((row, i) => <Row row={row} />)}
    </tbody>
  );
});

const Row = observer(({
  row,
}) => {
  return (
    <tr key={row.id} style={{height: row.rowHeight + 'px'}}>
      {row.cols.map((cell, i) => 
        <td key={cell.id}>{cell.value}</td>
      )}
    </tr>
  );
});

class DataModel {
  @observable rows = [
    { id: 1, rowHeight: 10, cols: [{ id: 1, value: 'one-1' }, { id: 2, value: 'one-2' }] },
    { id: 2, rowHeight: 5,  cols: [{ id: 1, value: 'two-1' }, { id: 2, value: 'two-2' }] },
    { id: 3, rowHeight: 10,  cols: [{ id: 1, value: 'three-1' }, { id: 2, value: 'three-2' }] },
  ];
  @observable rowLimit = 10;
  @observable colLimit = 10;

  @computed
  get limitedRows() {
    return this.limitData(this.rows, this.rowLimit).map(r => {
      return { id: r.id, cols: this.limitData(r.col, this.colLimit) };
    });
  }

  limitData(data, limit) {
    return limit ? data.slice(0, limit) : data;
  }
}

const data = new DataModel();

React.render(<HtmlTable data={data.limitedRows} />, document.body);
```

sources:

- https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/react-performance.html
- https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#faq
- https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Does the "dereference values as late as possible" holds true for react as well? I thought it would be the opposite :/.

Answer (score 2):

Make each row as a subcomponent and pass the props to that subcomponent.
That subcomponent will have its own state and can change without affecting all the rows

```
class HtmlTable extends React.Component {
   render() {
       var {rowCount, colCount, data} = this.props;
       var rows = this.limitData(data, rowCount);

       return <table>
           <tbody>{rows.map((row, i) => {
               var cols = this.limitData(row, colCount);

               return (<Row cols={cols} key={i}/>)
           })}</tbody>
       </table>
   }

   shouldComponentUpdate() {
       return false;
   }

   limitData(data, limit) {
       return limit ? data.slice(0, limit) : data;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would think this would limit re-renders. I wish whomever down voted you had left a comment.

Comment: The problem is not the component's state, it's reconciling the content of `<tbody>`, which consists of thousands of rows.

Comment: Okay, I don't get why people keep upvoting this answer. How can I update a row without updating the whole table this way? Imagine the user wants to change several rows' height - how do they do it?

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate on how to perform reconciliation within a worker (or a pool thereof) and transfer the result back to your main thread. There [exists a project](https://github.com/web-perf/react-worker-dom) that attempts to do just that, so you can experiment with their implementation.

Please note that I belong to the majority that has never encountered such requirements with React as yourself, so I can't provide any implementation details or further hints, but I believe `web-perf/react-worker-dom` may be a good place to start to start exploring and discovering similar solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is to change the **inline** styles.. maybe just use the styles for the particular `<tr>` outside of the table..

1. Generate the table, add classNames or ids to the `<tr>`
2. Generate the stylesheets and inject them into the `<head>`

... repeat the 2. step without changing the table

(just generate the css text with js)

```
.tr-0, #tr-0, .tr-1, ... { height: 10px }
...
```

I did't tested it, its just an idea, but I think this could be a way to go, if you don't want to touch the generated table after rendering..

You can use some really simple js to generate `<style>` and put them into the head:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.tr-0 { height: 10px; }';
// write some generator for the styles you have to change and add new style tags to the head...
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem is not that simple. But if its only related to style then keep styles of rows also in parent-table tag.

https://codepen.io/shishirarora3/pen/grddLm

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  renderStyle=(x,y)=> {
    console.log(x,y);
    let styleCode = `table tr:nth-child(${x}){ height: ${y} }`
    console.log(styleCode);
    return (
        <style>{ styleCode }</style>
    )
};
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.renderStyle(1,'100px')}
      <table>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
      </table>

    </div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```