# What ReactJS error Minified React error #301 mean?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS web app.  I made a change to code *that was working* and now I get an error:

`Error: Minified React error #301`

I can revert the code to get it working again but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to get this error.

NOTE: The last thing I added was:

`const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);`

So perhaps I can't use this...

*Does React have a list of error codes and explanations?*

## Searching for answers:

- Searched `React error codes and explanations`.  Nothing that helped.

Comment: It looks like your developing with the minified version of React, you would have meaningful error messages and stack traces with the development version. Here's [how to toggle the React version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22118915/1218980) you use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Does React have a list of error codes and explanations?**

There should be a URL included in the error that points you to a more complete description.
The pattern is:

```
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=###
```

So I plugged in 301 and got the following  https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=301 answer...

**Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**